# Hibernate PersistenceSet and Lombok EqualsAndHashCode issue

Tags: hibernate, hashset, hashcode, lombok, persistent-set

I have an entity, let's say an item which uses a Lombok annotation
`@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)` which autogenerates `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.
The entities are put inside a `HashSet` collection.

The problem is that when I am getting the collection from the DB (Spring `JPARepository` with Hibernate) `PersistentSet` proxy with my items in `HashSet` and when I am using the *Lombok `@EqualsAndHashCode`* the method  `persistentSet.contains(object)` returns `false`. When my `hashCode()` returns 1 or other value but *without the Lombok* auto-generated methods, it works fine -> `persistentSet.contains(object)` returns `true`. What else the Lombok autogenerated `hashCode()` also seems fine because it returns the constant value for the given object within session. So I am lost.

Maybe someone has an idea what may we wrong here !?

**Versions:**
Hibernate: 5.3.9.Final
Lombok: 1.18.10
database: MySQL
Spring: 5.1.9.RELEASE

Comment: I think we need some (maybe simplified) code here...

Comment: I don't know what pieces of code put here because everything looks fine and there is nothing special in my code. Just a class with an equals/hascode created(1)/autogenerated(2)  methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a reason. One of the object properties had had a @PostLoad annotation.
When invoking "persistentSet".contains(object) a hascode must be calculated before an initialization of the @PostLoad annotated properties.